# should process's comamnd line be constant during life-time of process?

Tags: linux, unix, process

In linux-based (unix-based) systems all processes have so called `cmdline`. Is it okay to change it during life-time of process? Fore example, modify `cmdline` with some progress/debugging information.
Are there any restrictions/conventions about working with processes `cmdline`?

Why am I asking? In out project, for monitoring particular subsystem, we're widely using approach with modification of `cmdline` for workers. For reading `cmdlines` we are using python library psutil. But from some version, this utility started to cache `cmdline` of process. I've created bug about it, but one of the authors claims, that `cmdline` should not be changed during process's life-time ([link to the bug](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/issues/detail?id=331))

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
under changing `cmdline` I don't have in mind changing exec arguments of process. I have in ming changing proctitle (http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/setproctitle/)

Answer (score 1):

There's only one situation where I would rename a command's process, in the case where you run a script with a #!'d subprocess which makes it difficult to find quickly with killall.

An example of this is running a Python script named 'foobar that's #!'d as:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

...
```

Which will show up in ps as

```
   0 18852 18810   0  1:09AM ttys006    0:03.50 /usr/bin/python -B ./foobar
```

In this case, renaming the process is beneficial since it will match expectations with the executor, if things go crazy you can quickly issue a killall without having to get out a magnifying glass. When I want a process dead, I want it dead.

However, in the case of renaming threads? I ran across that with celeryd and found it to be gratuitous and unnecessarily "clever". I would recommend against it. The argument that it's useful to find the state of threads is moot because the cost of enumerating the processes and peeking inside everyone's proc structure to extract a little bit of state information is much more costly than just logging it to syslog or stdout/err.

In the case where you're on Linux and enumerating through the /proc filesystem I would imagine it would be even more costly.

The argument that you shouldn't change it because you 'lose' the information about how the program was started.. I don't really agree with that since at least with Linux, /proc//cmdline has a limit of 4096 by default I believe - and the max length of a process argument is something huge like 1024*1024 bytes. (Think: ls -l /dir/with/100_thousand_files/*)

So you're not really ever guaranteed to have 'the real' cmdline and shouldn't expect it there.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with the person who claimed it shouldn't be changed. The command line is what the caller of your program gave to you as arguments. You are ill-advised mucking about with that.

If you want to give your child processes *different* command line arguments, the time to do that is when you "exec" them. I'm not sure if that's what you meant by "workers", your question is a little vague on the concept.

Perhaps it might help if you explain what your *requirement* is (in detail) rather than how you're trying to *implement* that requirement.

Comment: It is not to change the arguments. It is to change the publicly visible information about the process. Google `setproctitle`, this is the kind of use

Comment: Requirement is already implemented: monitor work of about 100 workers, from several multi processes pools. And yes, I was speaking exactly about `setproctitle`. Thanks, fork0

Comment: Using for monitoring manager's master process is always headache. You have to alway remember about states, use shared memory and values, etc. But using, instead, bullet-proof, native `ps` it much much more convenient - you just need to parse visible information about process (which is easy and takes moments) and if needed set proctitle with some valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that does not change for a process is the process id. Apart from that, anything can change. For example, if the process executes the *exec* system call, the code and data segments change and also the command line.

All caching systems improve speed but some data has to change in real time and the system logic including caches have to cater to it.